# I need to make two lists the same

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two quite long lists and I know that all of the elements of the shorter are contained in the longer, yet I need to isolate the elements in the longer list which are not in the shorter so that I can remove them individually from the dictionary I got the longer list from.
What I have so far is:

```
for e in range(len(lst_ck)):
    if lst_ck[e] not in lst_rk:
        del currs[lst_ck[e]]
        del lst_ck[e]
```

`lst_ck` is the longer list and `lst_rk` is the shorter, `currs` is the dictionary from which came `lst_ck`. If it helps, they are both lists of 3 digit keys from dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

Use sets to find the difference:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]

l2 = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8]

print(set(l2).difference(l1))
set([6, 7, 8]) # in l2 but not in l1
```

Then remove the elements.

```
 diff = set(l2).difference(l1):
 your_list[:] = [ele for ele in your_list of ele not in diff]
```

If you lists are very big you may prefer a generator expression:

```
your_list[:] = (ele for ele in your_list of ele not in diff)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care of multiple occurrences of the same item, use `set`.

```
diff = set(lst_ck) - set(lst_rk)
```

If you care, try this:

```
diff = [e for e in lst_rk if e not in lst_ck]
```

Comment: It should be the other way around,  you should subtract the small list from the large.